# Can I hide a tabulator column based on a condition?

Tags: tabulator

I want to hide a tabulator column based on a condition.  After looking over the tabulator documentation it doesn't seem possible, is that the case?  For example, if user X is auth don't show column B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing your exact setup, all I can give you is a general solution.

To hide a column, you just need to call `column.hide()` where `column` is the column component.  Another option is to call `table.hideColumn('name')` where `name` is the name of your column.

If you want to hide it during the creation of the table, you can set it in the column definition.  `{visible: false}`

Here is an example showing both methods.
https://jsfiddle.net/nrayburn/rsjopqfx/11/

Comment: That's about what I'm looking for.  If I added a JS condition statement the table fails to render.  https://jsfiddle.net/vbLm0nge/

Comment: Actually figured it out.  I see how `column.hide()` works.  http://tabulator.info/docs/4.0/columns